# How compile uClibc++ on openwrt

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

I working on debian to cross compile C++ to Openwrt Designated Driver. So far I have been using the static libc++ but my program is not working as it should when ran on the OpenWrt OS.

My build of OpenWrt has the uClibc++ shared objects. So how do I cross compile with uClibc++? right now I am just compiling C++ with the g++ files inside the stageing_dir. I have looked at the uClibc++ site but I cannot quite figure out how to use it.